# ajax form submission

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I am using a cakephp form. I have a dropdown select box. If dropdown value changes then the form should submit.Is there any method similar to form submission like this.form.submit for ajax forms. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use jQuery you could use the [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method and AJAXify a form like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myform').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(result) {
                // TODO: process the results
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Another possibility is to use the excellent [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/).

Answer (score 1):

If jquery is okay for you you can do

```
$('#myDropdown').change(function() {
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

if you want ajax replace line 2 as follows

```
var myForm = $(this).closest('form');
$.post(myForm.attr('action'), myForm.serialize(), function(data)
{
   /*do something on success*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dropdown elemnts **onChange** event

[Example](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

```
$('.target').change(function() {
  alert('Handler for .change() called.');
});
```